# WPF CollectionViewSource sorting issues with null values

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collectionviewsource

I've got a collectionviewsource whose source is an observable collection and i'm sorting like so ;

```
_viewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription() { PropertyName ="PropertyName", Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending });
```

this all works great until I attempt to sort by a property in the list that has a null value. I then get a InvalidOperationException, "Failed to compare two elements in the array"

Do I have to implement my own IComparer class in order to work around the null issue or am I missing a trick?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah to handle null values you have to write down your own `custom sorter` implementing `IComparer`. Can refer to this one just in case - [IComparer sample](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/320727#bookmark-3).

---

```
private class sortYearAscendingHelper : IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
      car c1=(car)a;
      car c2=(car)b;
      if(c1.year == null && c2.year == null)
         return 0;
      if(c1.year == null && c2.year != null)
         return -1;
      if(c1.year != null && c2.year == null)
         return 1;
      if (c1.year > c2.year)
         return 1;
      if (c1.year < c2.year)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Dead link to Bea Stollnitz (what a loss!!!), can you please post an example or working link?

Comment: @Hannish - Thanks. I have updated the link. Also post an example to avoid stale link issue in future. Hope that helps.!!

Comment: Thank you, you're most kind. By the way, do you know what happened to Bea's blog? It's huge that it disappeared...